# Using "Allow Text Entry" result as Piped Data in a Loop & Merge block

Tags: qualtrics

I have a multiple select option that allows text entry for an "other" choice at the bottom. Then I use the selected options from that question in a Loop & Merge block with a collection of other questions. I can the piped text variable `${lm://Field/1}` to get the selected question, as a header for the next block, for example:

> Please tell me more about `${lm://Field/1}`

But on the "other" choice, that will just say:

> Please tell me more about other

I would like it to use the value of the Text Entry field, but I can't find a piped text variable that would give me that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to pipe "Selected Choices - Entered Text" aka:

```
${q://QID1/ChoiceGroup/SelectedChoicesTextEntry}
```

That will pipe the text entry of the selected choice(s) that have text entry and the selected choice(s) for the choices that don't have text entry.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps below:

1. In Loop & Merge you choose "Loop based off of a question", and
   select the choose-all-that-apply Multiple Answer question that has
   the "Other" question with "Allow text entry" set to on.
2. In the adjacent drop down, choose "Selected Choices - Entered Text [object Object]".
3. Now, in your questions inside your Loop and Merge block, pipe the Loop & Merge field in the normal way with `${lm://Field/1}`.